# My 1 TB Hard Drive is getting full. How do I remove a group of documents?

Tags: hard-drive

I ran first aid on my 2015 MacBook Pro. I have 1 TB Hard Drive. It successfully ran the first aid; then it showed this:

99.42 GB (4.04 GB purgeable)

What does the 4,04 GB purgeable mean? Does this mean I need to replace the computer? I need to take documents off and put them on an external drive. Can that be done in a group transfer?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome. Can you add to your question the results (in text mode) of the terminal command : `diskutil list` ?

Comment: Purgeable means space that can be reclaimed as it's unimportant data, usually meant to speed up some things (caching).